# How to change API request call to fetch?

Tags: request, fetch, nuxt3, bitmex, nitro

I am practicing how to use the bitmex api.
It is an API endpoint that gets position information. It works when request is used, but it does not work when fetch is used. What's wrong with this? The code is the same, but I get an authentication error.

Code below when using request.

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const verb = 'GET'
  const path = '/api/v1/position'
  const expires = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 60 // 1 min in the future
  const data = {
    filter: { 'symbol': 'XBTUSD' },
  }

  // Pre-compute the postBody so we can be sure that we're using *exactly* the same body in the request
  // and in the signature. If you don't do this, you might get differently-sorted keys and blow the signature.
  const postBody = JSON.stringify(data)

  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret)
    .update(verb + path + expires + postBody)
    .digest('hex')

  const headers = {
    'content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    // This example uses the 'expires' scheme. You can also use the 'nonce' scheme. See
    // https://www.bitmex.com/app/apiKeysUsage for more details.
    'api-expires': expires,
    'api-key': apiKey,
    'api-signature': signature,
  }

  const requestOptions = {
    headers: headers,
    // Notice we are using testnet here. Switch to www to query the production site.
    url: 'https://www.bitmex.com' + path,
    method: verb,
    body: postBody,
  }

  request(requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

    console.log('body:', body)

    return {
      body
    }
  })
})
```

When using fetch.

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const verb = 'GET'
  const path = '/api/v1/position'
  const expires = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 60 // 1 min in the future
  const data = {
    filter: { 'symbol': 'XBTUSD' },
  }

  // Pre-compute the postBody so we can be sure that we're using *exactly* the same body in the request
  // and in the signature. If you don't do this, you might get differently-sorted keys and blow the signature.
  const postBody = JSON.stringify(data)

  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret)
    .update(verb + path + expires + postBody)
    .digest('hex')

  const headers = {
    'content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    // This example uses the 'expires' scheme. You can also use the 'nonce' scheme. See
    // https://www.bitmex.com/app/apiKeysUsage for more details.
    'api-expires': expires,
    'api-key': apiKey,
    'api-signature': signature,
  }

  const requestOptions = {
    headers: headers,
    // Notice we are using testnet here. Switch to www to query the production site.
    // url: 'https://www.bitmex.com' + path,
    method: verb,
    params: postBody,
  }

  const response = await $fetch('https://www.bitmex.com' + path, requestOptions)
  console.log('response:', response)

  return response
})
```

There is no problem when using request, but an authentication error occurs when using fetch.

I'm looking for someone who can advise me on what's wrong.